# How to add relative Layout below some element dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, parameters, android-relativelayout

Please help me to add a `RelativeLayout` below a `RadioButton` dynamically (I have to create `RelativeLayout` and `RadioButton` in class).

**Something like this:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
          android:text="RadioButton" />


    <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
          android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To View I can write:

```
myLayout.addView(myView, layoutParams);
```

But how about ViewGroup?

Comment: format code and add a missing bracket for RelativeLayout so the xml is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand u. Please check it and give me feedback. Thank you!

```
    LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RadioButton mRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    mRadioButton.setLayoutParams(p);
    mLayout.addView(mRadioButton);

    p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
    mLayout.addView(mRelativeLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it dosen't work as I need( If I need vertical orientation for mLayout your code works fine, but I need horizontal, because it have to contains more then one View horizontal (RadioButton, picture, etc) and RelativeLayout at the next line.

Comment: Why not add another linear layout inside existed linear layout, and set the orientation to horizontal? Then, you can put anything inside the new linear layout. Let's see if it is you want